# Odd blue borders in handsontable

Tags: handsontable

I have a very basic handsontable in my component in React.

```
<HotTable
    settings={{ licenseKey: 'non-commercial-and-evaluation' }}
    data={this.state.rawData}
    colHeaders={false}
    rowHeaders={false}
    readOnly={true}
    width="600"
    height="300"
/>
```

When I click on the top left cell, i see very odd blue borders as follows.
We could see that it is related to `wtBorder`.

[image]

Does anyone know what's wrong here? I tried to create a codesandbox, but in the snippet I could not reproduce the problem.

PS: additionally, there is a textbox generated at the bottom of the page, when we write text inside, it impacts cell values. It is strange as well.

Comment: What exactly you want to fix?

Comment: Don't you see the borders in the table strange?

Comment: Oh, i see, i guess if you turn off the background-color it would disappear

Comment: Maybe you can do this in styles just write !important

Comment: yes, but i don't want to hack, i hope we could solve this by some parameters that i send to the handstontable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you haven't imported the Handsontable CSS stylesheet and the only styles applied to your DOM are some inline styles that Handsontable adds.

Comment: indeed, adding `import "handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.css";` made it work.